# Permission inheritance after object creation

Tags: inheritance

I was recently made site admin for a sharepoint site (sharepoint 2007), previously maintained by my colleague. This site contains some lists, libraries whose permission I am not able to change. That is, I dont see the "Settings" option on these previously created objects.

I assume the issue is, inheritance doesn't work with retrospective effect. Hence I dont have the Full Access to the child objects even though I have Full access to the parent site. Is there something I can do to get full access to the child objects? Pls let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Get a site collection administrator to reset the permissions inheritance.  This will reset permissions to what exists on the site.  Then you'll have full control again and can reset permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're the farm admin, you can also grant yourself full control over all sites in a web application.

Go to SharePoint Central Administration --> Application Management --> Policy For Web Application (under the Application Security section)

In there, select your web application, and then add your user account with "Full Control".